# Unable to post any answer or comment with UNION - ALL

Tags: support, comments, answers

I've encountered issues posting comments or answers numerous times over the last month, I've narrowed it down that it only occurs when I use UNION and ALL next to each other (ie SQL).  If I separate them by a dash it works fine.

The error is always generic:  'An error occurred during ____ submission'  The blank being either comment or answer.

Someone suggested I post this question here.  I do not see a similar question, interestingly even trying to search the site for UNION and ALL errored, similarly separating them with + returns an error.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

This occurs in Chrome or IE, on Win 7, will test tonight from personal machines.

UPDATE:  Apparently through good coincidence I just never had attempted to use UNION ALL when answering questions from home, works fine here.  So it must indeed be some firewall/policy setting at my office with very specific criteria, never found any other code bits I couldn't post, and don't have a problem with UNION ALL on other sites.  Still interested to find out how it's being blocked given our high level of access.

Comment: UNION ALL test comment. Works fine here.

Comment: I'm seeing over 16k results. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22union+all%22

Comment: Yes, I get that it works for others, trying to find out why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I can't open your link, maybe that means the error is firewall/policy related, but I can use the terms on other sites without issue.

Comment: That is weird. Please report back if you find out anything.

Comment: I suppose the error comes from a Javascript postback to the server.  Do you see additional details if you use Chrome's developer tools, or Firefox's FireBug ?

Comment: Browser/operating system?

Comment: I remember reading about someone a while back that couldn't post SQL code because their company firewall was blocking it because they thought it was SQL injection. Did you find anything regarding your firewall policy?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum added that info to the question.

Comment: @FDinoff after not being able to browse to Bill's link I think it must be somehow related to firewall settings, it's odd though because I can post code and use the terms UNION and ALL together on other sites.

Comment: UNION ALL testing

Comment: UNION ALL - it works here!

Comment: @FDinoff It's definitely firewall related, works fine from home, oddly specific, affects only SQL Fiddle and stackoverflow as far as I can tell.  If you make an answer I'll choose it.

Comment: UNION ALL. This is just a test.

Comment: UNION ALL - testing (works for me on Chrome...)

Comment: UNION ALL testing works for me too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @FDinoff suggested, it seems to be firewall related.  I can use the terms together on many other sites, but for some reason on SQL Fiddle and SO I am prevented from doing so at work, despite being able to post many other bits of SQL code.

Trying to hunt down the exact rule that prevents this, but at least the cause of the problem is known.

Thanks to those of you that didn't just say "it works fine for me."

Update:  I found a workaround a while back, if I simply use two spaces instead of one, the firewall does not block it. `UNION  ALL`

Comment: Your answer works fine for me.

Comment: Your two-space workaround seems to imply a really crappy firewall.

Answer (score 3):

UNION ALL test answer. Works

Comment: UNION ALL testing

Comment: UNION ALL DROP TABLE Users

Comment: UNION ALL DELETE FROM Users WHERE display_name="Richard J.Ross III"

Comment: @GeorgeCummins \*Gasp\* I can't believe you deleted me! You're no longer invited to my birthday party :(

Comment: UNION ALL UPDATE Users SET coolness_factor = coolness_factor + 1 WHERE display_name = "Richard J. Ross III"; Friends?

Comment: select 'fish' union all select 'chips'